# jquery - resize table columns based on if visible and weight

Tags: jquery, html, css, math

Alright, so I'm working on a page that allows users to select which columns in a table they want to see.
 Some columns need to be wider than others due to content, so I need to give them a weight.

I can hide each column easily enough, but after hiding each column, I need to resize them.

So let's say I have this:

```
var columns = {
   //column name: weight
   id: 1,
   firstName: 2,
   lastName: 3,
   email: 3,
   address: 4
}
```

I could loop through and determine which ones are hidden pretty easily with jQuery, but how would I calculate what width to apply to each column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can do percentage widths, just add up the weight of all visible columns and use this formula -
column[i].css("width", ((Column weight) / (total weight of all visible columns) * 100) + "%");

Comment: I figured you meant total **weight** of all columns, and that seems to have worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

CSS can set width using a percentage, so you could set it to (Weight/Sum_of_Visible_Weights)*100 %. Or if you plan on a definite total table width, multiple the percent by that yourself and set the width in pixels (or whatever unit).